# Profiling Camel routes using JConsole

Tags: profiling, apache-camel, jmx, jconsole

I have an application consisting of number of Camel routes; I would need to profile them using JConsole. I have noticed upon bringing up the JConsole and selecting the local JVM that is running these Camel routes; various MBeans under domain name org.apache.camel is displaying information about such as End points, Processors, Routes etc. Note: I did not setup any instructions given on the link [Camel JMX](http://camel.apache.org/camel-jmx.html#CamelJMX-HowtousetheJMXNotificationListenertolistenthecamelevents?)

I would like to know how would these instructions differ in the information display in the later case?

Comment: can you elaborate on what you are asking exactly?

Comment: I agree. I don't understand anything of the question.

Comment: Let me elaborate. I am using Apache Camel integration framework to implement routing in my application using Java DSL. So as to profile my application I brought up JConsole; it is already displaying information under MBeans tab with org.apache.camel domain about Endpoints, Processors, Routes and so on. Meanwhile I found about how to JMX enable Camel routes at http://camel.apache.org/camel-jmx.html#CamelJMX-HowtousetheJMXNotificationListenertolistenthecamelevents?  I wonder if it is redundant since Camel routes are already JMX enabled OR if I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default, JMX instrumentation agent is enabled in Camel which means that Camel runtime creates and registers MBean management objects with a MBeanServer instance in the VM. This allows Camel users instantly obtain insights into how Camel routes perform down to the individual processor's level.
>
> The supported types of management objects are endpoint , route, service, and processor. Some of these management objects also expose lifecycle operations in addition to performance counter attributes.

The other link you referenced describes how to programmatically create listeners for JMX events...